# onpaste event not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am using the javascript function to append the values....when i use the onkeypress event the values get appended properly with an alert message when there is slash(/) given.....but when i use onpaste event the values are not getting appended properly to the array....could someone help me out with this

```js
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    
 try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
         
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
            
        }
        else { return true; }
       
        if ((charCode == 47)){
         
         alert("Please use any other charachter! ");
       return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed"  id='+tables+' onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets()" >
<thead>
<tr><th></th><th>Code</th><th>Sub Category</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
</div>';
```

Comment: you have `if...else if...else` nothing will be executed afterwards...

Comment: Where do you listen for a paste event, what are you doing with the paste event? What doesn't work.

Comment: instead of using keypress event if i use onpaste ....that doesnt work

Comment: Well of course, what do you expect this function to do on a paste event? This function blocks a keypress event in case the key that was pressed had the keyCode value set to 47 (btw I'm not even sure what key it is...). A paste event doesn't have a keyCode property, and thus, your function is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<body>` like this and try again.

```js
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
    
 try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
         
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
            
        }
        else { return true; }
       
        if ((charCode == 47)){
         
         alert("Please use any other charachter! ");
       return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
```

```html
 <body onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets()">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed"  id='+tables+'  >
            <thead>
                <tr><th></th><th>Code</th><th>Sub Category</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you attach a keypress event to an element that isn't like `<input>`, when you press the key, the focus is not in that element. 
That's why table couldn't recognize the event..

Comment: for the keypress event its working fine......but i need to provide it with onpaste event.....for the this(onpaste) event its not working

Comment: But your code you've given didn't even work with keypress... so I fixed it first...